Book series set after a nuclear war - sickly hacker genius and an Amazonian goth battle-priestess/nun
Post nuclear war. Set in London, but it isn't called London it is called the Metrozone or something.
The protagonist is a sickly hacker genius who swears in Russian or something. He has a wrist mounted terminal called a RAT?
The main female character is an Amazonian goth battle-priestess/nun.
The story might have to do with birth of AI?
It might be a trilogy.
There was trippy fractal art on the cover in bold simple colours.

The mention of "Metrozone" immediately jogged a memory in me, and I believe that this is Equations of Life a novel from 2011 by Simon Morden, and the first in the Samuil Petrovitch trilogy.
The central character is a Russian hacker called Samuil Petrovitch, who lives in the Metrozone, a city which used to be London, and is the only city left in England. From the cover blurb:

Samuil Petrovitch is a survivor.
He survived the nuclear fallout in St. Petersburg and hid in the
London Metrozone – the last city in England. He’s lived this long
because he’s a man of rules and logic.
For example, getting involved = a bad idea.
But when he stumbles into a kidnapping in progress, he acts without
even thinking. Before he can stop himself, he’s saved the daughter of
the most dangerous man in London.
And clearly saving the girl = getting involved.
Now, the equation of Petrovitch’s life is looking increasingly
complex.
Russian mobsters + Yakuza + something called the New Machine Jihad =
one dead Petrovitch.
But Petrovitch has a plan – he always has a plan – he’s just not sure
it’s a good one.

He swears extensively in Russian, and indeed one of the main characters, Maddy is described on a review on Goodreads as "a 2+ meter tall, incredibly strong nun, carrying her Vatican-approved gun, so she can protect her parish priest". I can also confirm that the cover resembles trippy fractal art:


Oh no, we did it again :-)

This is it thank you

@dnaurgde If this is the book please click the tick mark to the left of Clara's answer to mark it as accepted. Thanks :-)

and needless to say, you are a gentleman @JohnRennie  ;)
